# ASM: Format unknown: 30790BF0H

Tags: dll, assembly, reverse-engineering

I disassembled a dll and found a line:

```
push    30790BF0h
```

What's the 30790BF0h? How can I convert it to an integer, I just
want to know the integer value of it. If it's 32 everything is fine.
So is there an online calculator for this or?

Answer (score 1):

It's in [*hexadecimal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (i.e. *base-16*) representation.  In other programming languages, you might see it written `0x30790BF0`, `$30790BF0` or `16#30790BF0#`.

There are millions of online calculators that will do the transformation; even the Windows calculator can do it!

*[Incidentally, the value of that particular number is 813239280 in decimal.]*

Comment: Ok, but for hex 30790BF0h I get dec 813239280, it should be 32. Or what I need is to change the 30790BF0h to have a representation for decimal 256. The original number should be 32, the modified 256(but in this hex crap).

Comment: @luac: I cannot tell you why it's not 32.  You would need to consult the original source code to establish that.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more context.  That could be pushing the address of the string "32", even.  Seeing it in context, with system or C library calls near it, could help determine what that is representing.